# Data that can be seen in the console is not displaying in the view

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am grabbing data from Firestore. In the console, the data is displaying like this. 
[image]

But when, I try to display the data in the view, I don't see any data. I just see empty cards.

HTML

```
 <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="12" >
        <ion-card *ngFor ="let favorite of favoriteList">
          <img [src]="favorite?.image">
          <div class="card-title">{{favorite?.title}}</div>
        </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
```

TS

```
 favoriteList: any;  
 public favoriteListRef: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;

 this.favoriteService.getfavoriteList().then(favoriteListSnapshot => {
      this.favoriteList = [];
      favoriteListSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
        this.favoriteList.push({
          id: snap.id,
          image: snap.data().image,
          favorite: snap.data().favourite
        });
        console.log(snap.data().favourite)
        return false;
      });
    });
  }
```

Favorite Service

```
async getfavoriteList(): Promise<firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot> {
    const user: firebase.User = await this.authService.getUser();
    if (user) 
          {
    this.FavoriteListRef = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection(`userFavorites`);
    return this.FavoriteListRef.where('uid', '==', user.uid).get();
              }
           } 
       }
```

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you working with the `OnPush` strategy ?

Comment: Image seems to be an array and title is empty in your response. So empty cards seems to be expected?

Comment: I think nircraft has got the right idea. For the future you can use the [json pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) to dump out the `favourite` by putting `{{ favorite | json }}`. This lets you be sure the data is really there. In your case you should just expand `image` and see what properties are inside of it.

Answer (score 2):

In your response image is an `Array`. You can't see the images because `"src"` attribute on `<img>` is not getting proper src url to load.

You can use first url in image array as `src` for your image.

```
<img [src]="favorite?.image[0]">
```